# MainActivity.OnActivityResult(int, Result, Intent)': no suitable method found to override in Xamrine

Tags: xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I am trying to create project in xamarin but it causes error when i try to use method in mainactivity.cs file in Xamarin.android project -

```
protected override void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
}
```

Error is :

```
MainActivity.OnActivityResult(int, Result, Intent)': no suitable method found to override
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Activity.OnActivityResult(Int32, Result, Intent) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) , we can see that the signature for Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult is

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("onActivityResult", "(IILandroid/content/Intent;)V", "GetOnActivityResult_IILandroid_content_Intent_Handler")]
protected virtual void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data);
```

So we have to override that to receive the activity result like

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(Int32 requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // add some code you like 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change your protected modifier in the method signature, like this:

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //Your code here
}
```